# Web API 2 Patch Delta<T> doesn't deserialize Timespan property

Tags: odata, asp.net-web-api2

I want to use Patch with Delta to update an object, which has Timespan property
i haven't got any error, but the Timespan properties are all 0:00:00, i think they're simple ignored.

i can see 0 at the timespan property just when the method in the controller stops at the breakpoint. i don't make any change on the data at that stage.
it is sure i send not empty timespan from the client

```
{"TevID":2,"TevName":"this is the name","TotalTime":"01:03:00","FreeTime":"02:30:00"}

[HttpPatch]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Patch(int id, Delta<TTevekenyseg> modified) {
Log.Info("Update-ID: {0}", id);
...
}
```

do you have any information, if Delta works for Timespans?

Comment: What is your code doing when the timespan is zero? When posting? At any other moment? Please, add soem context to your question. Even better, some sample code.

Comment: some sample code added

Answer (score 0):

Delta<T> doesn't work for TimeSpans.  It's a pretty flawed class so I wrote my own called Patchable<T>.  The main problem I found was Delta<T>'s incompatibility with JSON.Net.  Its lack of support for TimeSpan was confirmation I did the right thing.

See [the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27054888/json-net-deserializeobject-failing-with-odata-delta-integers-only) (a long read sorry)

The answer has TrySetInt32.  The equivalent method TrySetTimeSpan works perfectly.